# How to do a index/match conditional formatting on a cell that contains structured table references

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get the cell to be colored red using `conditional formatting` when the matched text is "Monthly Regular"

The sample code is below:

```
=IF(index(Salary[Type],match($A2,Salary[Person],0))="Monthly Regular",TRUE,FALSE)
```

The error i'm getting is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a structured table reference in a conditional formatting formula, use the `INDIRECT` function. So your conditional formatting formula becomes:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("Salary[Type]"),MATCH($A2,INDIRECT("Salary[Person]"),0))="Monthly Regular"
```

Note also that you don't need the `IF`... `TRUE,FALSE` function.

Comment: Thanks this works. Never knew you could use 2 equal signs without parenthesis I got confused there